# grep in .txt for specific characters, interpolate lines where those characters are found, write result to .txt

Tags: r, text, output, txt

Thanks to those who pointed out that `grep` doesn't work well on entire data-frames. I'm now working directly with a txt file, Test.txt, and have another question...

The contents of Test.txt look like this:

```
             V1            V2
1       chambrun     ʃ ɑ̃ b ʁ ɛ̃
2       chambrun     ʃ ɑ̃ b ʁ œ̃
3           alun         a l ɛ̃
4        emprunt       ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃
5      demprunta   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t a
6  fempruntaient   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t ɛ
7     empruntait   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t ɛ
8    eempruntant   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t ɑ̃
9      gemprunte     ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t
10   hempruntent     ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t
11    demprunter   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
12    vempruntes     ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t
13   hemprunteur ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t œ ʁ
14  eemprunteurs ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t œ ʁ
15    bempruntez   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
16     kemprunts       ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃
17 nempruntèrent ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t ɛ ʁ
18     vemprunté   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
19    fempruntée   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
20   wempruntées   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
21    2empruntés   ɑ̃ p ʁ ɛ̃ t e
```

I want to:

1. `grep` in Test.txt for the characters 'un' and 'ɛ̃' (they will always be in the same row)
2. Append a line which is identical except that 'ɛ̃' is replaced with   'œ̃'
3. Output the contents of Test.txt, plus the appended lines, to another .txt

But all I can get is an output file with the line indices where the `grep` pattern was found, including indices of the appended lines, not a file with the actual text of the lines.

I tried this:

```
# 1. Find lines containing both "un" and "ɛ̃"
lines_with_pattern <- grep('un.*ɛ̃',readLines("Test.txt"))

# 2. Duplicate the line in which the pattern occurs
modified_lines <- character()
for (line in lines_with_pattern) {
  modified_lines <- c(modified_lines, line, gsub("ɛ̃", "œ̃", line))

# 3. Combine modified lines with original lines
all_lines <- c('Test.txt', modified_lines)

# 4. Sort the lines alphabetically
sorted_lines <- sort(all_lines)

# 5. Write the sorted lines to .txt
writeLines(sorted_lines, 'myfile.txt', sep = '\n')
```

I think this is nearly there. But what do I need to change to make it output the original and appended text, not the indices of the lines where the pattern was matched? Thanks!

Comment: Check the `?grep` help page. By default `grep` just returns the index of the matching value. If you want the value itself, use `value=TRUE` when calling `grep()`

Comment: By Jove, I do believe he's got it! Thanks very much @MrFlick --and sorry for the noob question.